# Skirting board filler chipping off

Tags: painting, wood-filler, skirting

We’re about to paint our skirting board with black gloss paint but some of the filler is chipping off in places.

Should we remove the areas of filling that are chipping off and refill those only or should we try to remove all of the filling and completely redo from scratch? What is the best product to fill with?

And do we need to sand down the original gloss paint before painting over with new black gloss?

[image: chipped filling on skirt]

Comment: Just a note about gloss black: black (actually *all dark*) paints do not cover well, so use premium paint brushes and expect to apply a second coat. Also, gloss black paint will tend to show defects clearly, so expect any dents, divots, cracks, nail holes, etc. to be visible if they are not repaired.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to achieve a perfect seam or just looking to hide the gap?

You can fill it with paintable caulk/silicone and proceed with painting.

Yes, gloss paint needs to be scuffed up so that new paint can adhere properly unless you are applying an oil-based paint.

If you want to turn this painting project into a painful multi-day renovation then remove the skirting, sand or scrape down the protruding paint from both the wall and skirting, patch the wall with mud, sand, prime, re-attach the skirting, apply paintable caulk or silicone, and finally paint the skirting and wall.

Comment: While the advice in the last para is "painful" and "multi-day", it is the _one true way_ to a quality finish.

Comment: @FreeMan Thanks, and I applaud you for finding this answer 1 month later!

Comment: Community bump because there is no accepted answer... :/

Answer (score 1):

I would sand the board slightly to remove the gloss paint sheen. Then I would put masking tape or the newer type edging tape, green or blue, on both the wall and baseboard, just past where you want to fill. Clean out the loose debris and use a paintable silicone caulking to fill the slot. After you add the caulking run your finger along that caulking to give you a smooth finish. When the caulking has been smoothed, remove the tape to leave a nice straight edge.  After the caulking has dried you can paint the baseboard as you like.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to "rake" out the loose and jagged paint in the gap so that it can then be filled. After cleaning out the gap you should use a latex caulk to fill the gap. You may be able to find a color to match the paint you intend to use.

Inject the caulk along the gap,press it in with your finger and wipe gently with a dampened sponge until you're satisfied with how it looks.

I would suggest making sure the molding (trim) piece in the picture isn't loose and if it is to re-secure it with finish nails and such.

No need to de-gloss before painting, but a quick cleaning with TSP, ammonia, Windex will guarantee a successful paint job.